# Other way to install ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I want to install Ubuntu in a notebook in witch I have already installed windows 10. I know how to do that but I also know that if I uninstall ubuntu I'll lose grub. I don't have a cd with windows, neither an image of it, so I'm searching a way to don't lose grub, or find a way to boot windows, in case I want to uninstall ubuntu.

Comment: You can always download a Windows iso. Also you can install Ubuntu into VirtualBox.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't want to install Ubuntu in a virtual machine. There aren't other way to uninstall ubuntu without losing grub?

Comment: Yes install another Linux (grub gets deleted if there is no system installed that requires grub).

Comment: There is also  GRUB4DOS https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/files/ but this is turning out to be more a Windows problem than an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Your factory installed Windows 10 is in UEFI mode; the Ubuntu you'll be installing should be as well. With a (working properly) UEFI mode the issue you describe is no longer an issue, there's always an independent Windows bootloader at your ESP. But better to have Windows media anyway and you should have one even if you only have Windows. And again, you can download it for free legally from Microsoft.